# How to calculate events per day in R including dates when no events occurred?

Tags: r

I would like to create a data frame in which in the first column I will have all the dates from a certain period of time and in the second the number of events that occurred on each date including dates when no events occurred. I would also like to count the events to which specific factors have been assigned

The first data frame in which I have the events with dates for a given date:

```
Row Sex Age      Date
1    2   36   2004-01-05
2    1   47   2004-01-06
3    1   26   2004-01-10
4    2   23   2004-01-20
5    1   50   2004-01-27
6    2   35   2004-01-28
7    1   35   2004-01-30
8    1   38   2004-02-06
9    2   29   2004-02-11
```

Where in the column "Sex" 1 means female and 2 male.

Second data frame in which I have dates from the examined period:

Row    Date

```
1  2004-01-05
 2  2004-01-06
 3  2004-01-07
 4  2004-01-08
 5  2004-01-09
 6  2004-01-10
 7  2004-01-11
 8  2004-01-12
 9  2004-01-13
10  2004-01-14
```

I want to get a data frame that looks like this:

```
Row    Date       Events (All)   Events (Female)   Events (Male)
 1  2004-01-05         1                0                1
 2  2004-01-06         1                1                0
 3  2004-01-07         0                0                0
 4  2004-01-08         0                0                0
 5  2004-01-09         0                0                0
 6  2004-01-10         0                1                0
 7  2004-01-11         0                0                0
 8  2004-01-12         0                0                0
 9  2004-01-13         0                0                0
10  2004-01-14         0                0                0
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one method:

```r
library(data.table)
library(magrittr) # just for %>%
out <- dat1 %>%
  dcast(Date ~ Sex, data = ., fun.aggregate = length) %>%
  setnames(., c("1", "2"), c("Female", "Male")) %>%
  .[ dat2[ , .(Date)], on = "Date" ] %>%
  .[, lapply(.SD, function(a) replace(a, is.na(a), 0)), ] %>%
  .[, All := Female + Male ]
out
#           Date Female Male All
#  1: 2004-01-05      0    1   1
#  2: 2004-01-06      1    0   1
#  3: 2004-01-07      0    0   0
#  4: 2004-01-08      0    0   0
#  5: 2004-01-09      0    0   0
#  6: 2004-01-10      1    0   1
#  7: 2004-01-11      0    0   0
#  8: 2004-01-12      0    0   0
#  9: 2004-01-13      0    0   0
# 10: 2004-01-14      0    0   0
```

Note that the use of `lapply` might not be the overall fastest method to replace `NA` with 0, but it gets the point across. Also, I use `magrittr::%>%` merely to break out steps, this can be done easily without `%>%`.

Data:

```r
dat1 <- fread(text = "
Row Sex Age      Date
1    2   36   2004-01-05
2    1   47   2004-01-06
3    1   26   2004-01-10
4    2   23   2004-01-20
5    1   50   2004-01-27
6    2   35   2004-01-28
7    1   35   2004-01-30
8    1   38   2004-02-06
9    2   29   2004-02-11")

dat2 <- fread(text = "
Row Date
 1  2004-01-05
 2  2004-01-06
 3  2004-01-07
 4  2004-01-08
 5  2004-01-09
 6  2004-01-10
 7  2004-01-11
 8  2004-01-12
 9  2004-01-13
10  2004-01-14")
```

---

A `tidyvers`ion:

```r
dat1 <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = "
Row Sex Age      Date
1    2   36   2004-01-05
2    1   47   2004-01-06
3    1   26   2004-01-10
4    2   23   2004-01-20
5    1   50   2004-01-27
6    2   35   2004-01-28
7    1   35   2004-01-30
8    1   38   2004-02-06
9    2   29   2004-02-11")

dat2 <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = "
Row Date
 1  2004-01-05
 2  2004-01-06
 3  2004-01-07
 4  2004-01-08
 5  2004-01-09
 6  2004-01-10
 7  2004-01-11
 8  2004-01-12
 9  2004-01-13
10  2004-01-14")

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
as_tibble(dat1) %>%
  group_by(Date, Sex) %>%
  tally() %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = "Date", names_from = "Sex", values_from = "n",
              values_fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
  rename(Female = "1", Male = "2") %>%
  left_join(select(dat2, Date), ., by = "Date") %>%
  mutate_at(vars(Female, Male), ~ replace(., is.na(.), 0)) %>%
  mutate(All = Female + Male)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have tried tidyversion. Unfortunately, an error occurs that I don't know how to deal with.

"ERROR: `by` can't contain join column `Date` which is missing from RHS"

Any idea what might be causing it?

Comment: That says that the second frame you are joining in does not have the `Date` column in it. Ensure case is the same, etc. (In the case with `left_join(dat2, .)`, the rhs is `dat1` post-pipe.)